# Files.copy not recognising binary files on Windows (Java)

Tags: java, windows, file-io

So I am trying to copy some files with `Files.copy()`, and while it is working fine in Mac, and works to copy text files on Windows, when I try to copy a binary file I just get the error:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\path\to\file

My function is:

```
private void copyFiles()
{

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(); //This is set up outside the function
    temp.add("file1");
    temp.add("file2");   //etc
    String AlphaSimFileName = "folderName";  //This is actually set outside the function
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    Path baseAlphaName = Paths.get(currentDir, AlphaSimFileName);
    Path baseDirectoryName = Paths.get(currentDir, name);

    System.out.println(""+baseAlphaName.toString());
    System.out.println(""+baseDirectoryName.toString());
//        for (String l: MyFunctions.getFilesAsString()) //gives the list of files to copy.
    for (String l: temp)
    {
        Path p1 = Paths.get(baseAlphaName.toString(), l);
        Path p2 = Paths.get(baseDirectoryName.toString(), l);

        try
        {
            Files.copy(p1, p2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The reason for this was that Windows was automatically hiding file extensions, so the file that I was trying to move (i.e. without the extension) didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it manually first. Use \\ instead of \ when you hardcode the path for Windows using Java. Also, the file extension may be missing.

Comment: Yeah, Windows was automatically hiding the file extensions, which was causing it to fail.